# How do I edit or override the footer of ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

How do I edit or override the footer of Active_Admin?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Answer:**

In your rails app, create this file: `app/admin/footer.rb`

The content would be something like:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class Footer < Component

      def build
        super :id => "footer"                                                    
        super :style => "text-align: right;"                                     

        div do                                                                   
          small "Cool footer #{Date.today.year}"                                       
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Don't forget! **restart** the app/server.

Any ActiveAdmin layout component can be customized like this.

**More about it:**

Why does it work?
This is Ruby's magic sauce. We are reopening the definition of the Footer class and changing it for our custom content.

Is it totally customizable? I don't know. This is the inheritance path:

ActiveAdmin

```
class Component < Arbre::Component
class Footer < Component
```

Arbre

```
class Component < Arbre::HTML::Div
```

This means that we can use Arbre's DSL directly.

Comment: build now requires one argument, `build(namespace)`.

Comment: This solution is now obsolete, please see the https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/1714

Answer (score 18):

If all you want to do is change or delete the 'powered by' message, what you can do is change its value in a locale file. Example, edit `config/locales/en.yml`

And use something like this:

```
en:                                                                              
  active_admin:                                                                  
    powered_by: "Powered by hamsters"
```

Why this works:

The default locale for a rails app is english, the `en` locale file.

Comment: Nice, just what I needed

Answer (score 4):

Between v1.0.4pre and v.1.0.5pre, the previous method of overriding `Footer#build` no longer works well, and the new API is

```
ActiveAdmin.application.footer = proc {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For v.1.0.0.pre5 I found that the Accepted Answer requires a small additiion, namely adding a variable to build as below:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class Footer < Component

      def build (namespace)
        super :id => "footer"                                                    
        super :style => "text-align: right;"                                     

        div do                                                                   
          small "Cool footer #{Date.today.year}"                                       
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

From [gist](https://gist.github.com/pcreux/3058773)
create file in `lib/footer.rb`

```
class Footer < ActiveAdmin::Component
  def build
    super :id => "footer"
    span "My Awesome footer"
  end
end
```

add to `initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
 ......some config here....

  config.view_factory.footer = Footer

 ......some config here....
end
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out what `lib` folder should I be using. Maybe it works in older versions. My guess is that you meant `app/admin/`.

Comment: no i mean `lib/` folder and i use this feature on my project.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMHO.  Monkey patching might work in the short term, but in the long term is causes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 2):

Newer version of ActiveAdmin provides configurable option to set footer.

[ActiveAdmin Footer Customization](https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#footer-customization)

`config.footer = "MyApp Revision v1.3"`

Footer can be configured using proc, where you can even render partial.

[ActiveAdmin Footer Customization using proc](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/2bb5021f81c208ec201e278be0d6cf67d70e0924/features/footer.feature#L25)

`config.footer = proc { "Enjoy MyApp Revision 123, #{controller.current_admin_user.try(:email)}!" }`

[PR which added the ability to customize the footer](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/4641)