# How to remove the ActiveAdmin link in the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink, activeadmin

The link seen as "powered by ActiveAdmin" on every page of the app using this ActiveAdmin gem, can it be removed?? If yes How?? Is there any legality associated with the link??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can either provide your custom footer:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.view_factory.footer = MyFooter
end
class MyFooter < ActiveAdmin::Component
  def build
    super(id: "footer")
    para "Copyright #{Date.today.year} Your Company"
  end
end
```

Or you can provide an alternative translation:

```
en:
  active_admin:
    powered_by: "Your custom text"
```

Comment: Thank u so much seanlinsley :) What if i want neither of them?? like I dont want a footer at all??

Comment: Could you not provide an empty string?

Comment: Yeah :P you are right.. There is no legality associated rt?? Like I can use the gem without that link??

Comment: Active Admin uses the MIT License, so no, you can do whatever you want. It's more of a goodwill thing than anything. The more people that use Active Admin, the better it can become. Having that link in your footer lets people discover Active Admin.

Comment: Might be debatable but I like this way of customization better - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20510985/753705, putting it here just for reference of people trying to customize AA footer.

Comment: I get error  uninitialized constant MyFooter (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

NB @seanlinsley's solution

Define `class MyFooter` in config/initializers/active_admin.rb above the
`ActiveAdmin.setup do` definition.